# c# add comma before every numbers in my string except first number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing as application in asp.net mvc.

I have a string like below

`string myString = "1A5#3a2@"`

now I want to add a comma after every occurrence of number in my string except the first occurrence.

like

`string myNewString "1A,5#,3a,2@";`

I know I can use loop for this like below
myNewString

```
foreach(var ch in myString) 
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')     
    {                  
        myNewString = myNewString ==""?"":myNewString + "," + Convert.ToString(ch);
    }     
    else     
    {         
        myNewString = myNewString ==""? Convert.ToString(ch): myNewString + Convert.ToString(ch);     
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are sequences of multiple digits? For example `1A2B3334D5E` What should happen?

Comment: Please try to provide more sample input and output pairs than one. Otherwise you will receive answers which are specific to this example.

Comment: what is the question in here actually? are you looking for any alternative approaches to solve this?

Comment: yes and found the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so, as I understood the below code will work for you

```
StringBuilder myNewStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var ch in myString) 
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')     
    {                  
        if (myNewStringBuilder.Length > 0)
        {
            myNewStringBuilder.Append(",");
        }
        myNewStringBuilder.Append(ch);
    }     
    else     
    {         
        myNewStringBuilder.Append(ch);    
    }
}
myString = myNewStringBuilder.ToString();
```

**NOTE**

Instead of using `myNewString` variable, I've used `StringBuilder` object to build up the new string. This is more efficient than concatenating strings, as concatenating strings creates new strings and discards the old ones. The `StringBuilder` object avoids this by efficiently storing the string in a mutable buffer, reducing the number of object allocations and garbage collections.

Comment: What if the string is `"12A5#3a2@"`? You will get `1,2A,5#,3a,2@`. As far as i've understood the requirement, the correct result would be `12A,5#,3a,2@`. But maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: actually I have written the answer as per my understanding, and as I understood he wants to aapend `","` before every integer value no matter what the input is

Answer (score 4):

You could use this `StringBuilder` approach:

```
public static string InsertBeforeEveryDigit(string input, char insert)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new(input);
    for (int i = sb.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(sb[i]) && char.IsDigit(sb[i+1]))
        {
            sb.Insert(i+1, insert);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

---

```
 Console.Write(InsertBeforeEveryDigit("1A5#3a2@", ',')); // 1A,5#,3a,2@
```

**Update**: This answer gives a different result than the one from TWM if the string contains consecutive digits like here: `"12A5#3a2@"`. My answer gives: `12A,5#,3a,2@`,
TWM's gives: `1,2A,5#,3a,2@`. Not sure what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

```cs
string myString = "1A5#3a2@";
var result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(?<=\d\D*)\d\D*", ",$&");
```

Regex explanation ([@regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kVb4q6/1)):

- `\d\D*` - matches every occurrence of a digit with any following non-digits (zero+)
- `(?<=\d\D*)` - negative lookbehind so we have at least one group with digit before (i.e. ignore first)

This can be updated if you need to handle consecutive digits (i.e. "1a55b" -> "1a,55b") by changing `\d` to `\d+`:

```cs
var result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(?<=\d+\D*)\d+\D*", ",$&");
```